# Finding the line that has the most words and output it to text file. C++

Tags: c++, string

So I have a file with like 5-6 lines of text, and I need to find which one has the most words and output it into another file. Any of you have suggestions?

I'm not that advanced in C++, I' using classes, arrays, no vectors or such.

Other code is rather irrelevant in my program, but if you need it i'll paste it here.

EDIT: http://pastebin.com/zh7HPCtT here's my code, the first part of it finds how many words in a line are longer than the first word.

I haven't added anything else for the other half of the assignment.

Comment: please show us what you have tried, and what you are having trouble with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

- read each line
- count the words in it
- if it has more words than any other line you've seen, save it
- after the file is exhausted, print the saved line

Comment: I have an undefined number of lines, also, how do I save the line? do I just string longest= ... ? Also, If there are two lines or more with the same number of words I have to output it as well.

Comment: TIAS: "Try It And See" :-)

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest solutions is to use a string `max` that you will use in your loop.

Then you loop over all lines in your file, and for each line `line` you compare the number of words in `line` against the number of words in `max`, and if `line` has more words, assign it to `max`.

After you have done that for all lines, open a file or just dump to standard output (enabling your user to redirect your output to some file itself), and print `max`.

The core algorithm is very much like finding the maximum of two numbers, and in fact you can just use `std::max` from the standard library, with your own comparator.

---

Just for fun, here's a very suboptimal solution:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


std::string longest_phrase (std::istream &is) {
    std::string longest, current_line;
    while (getline(is, current_line))
        longest = max(longest, current_line, [] (std::string const &lhs, std::string const &rhs) {
            std::stringstream lhss(lhs), rhss(rhs);
            std::string sink;
            int words_lhs = 0, words_rhs = 0;
            while (lhss >> sink) ++words_lhs;
            while (rhss >> sink) ++words_rhs;
            return words_lhs < words_rhs;
        });
    return longest;
}

std::string longest_phrase (std::string const &content) {
    std::istringstream ss(content);
    return longest_phrase(ss);
}


int main () {
    std::cout << longest_phrase("Hello, I am a cat!\n"
                                "Hello, I am an unhappy bear!\n"
                                "Pardon?!\n"
                                "WtfOMG!?=§\"$%&/!!?µ€@+%$§==!!!") << '\n';
}
```

It will output `Hello, I am an unhappy bear!\n`. There's a lot of resource waste and you should make it more stateful, but it will serve you as a starting point.